# Count of a string in a list

Tags: python, function

I need help:

I want to write function that: takes a list as a input and return count of specific string.

If function input is  `x=[a,a,b,c]` function need return `2` (`a` is two times in this list).

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> def F(seq, string):
        return seq.count(string)

>>> F(['a','a','b','c'], 'a')
2
```

Equivalent to:

```
def F(seq, string):
    n = 0
    for x in seq:
        if x == string:
            n += 1
    return n
```